# How to download an app from another region/country?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, localization

I've found duplicate posts, but they are outdated.  The solutions no longer work as some of the apps have been deprecated, and things have changed since 2013.  My phone is NOT rooted, I have a HTC ONE M8, running Android 6.0.

I'm in the Middle East (but my Google account is based in the USA since I live there), and I'm trying to download an app that is only available here in the Middle East.  However, when I search for the app in my play store, I'm finding only the USA equivalent, which doesn't have the features I need while I'm here.  I'm physically not in the USA though, and my sim card is a local one from the Middle East so when I access the play store its weird how I'm still getting US based apps.

I've tried changing my country in payments.google.com > settings, and erased all data of my play store and play services, went back in and its still showing me results for the USA.  The only thing that makes sense to me is that somewhere in my google account it still has my country/region as USA.  How can I change this?  Would creating another account be a good idea?  I just don't want to have to sign out of my google account, but if its the only way I guess I'll try that.

If the best solution is creating a google account, I've actually gone ahead and done that, but how do I switch accounts?  I don't want to lose any data in the process of switching accounts.

Comment: The VPN solution mentioned in [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in Google's Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12538/16575) doesn't work either?Or the "Hola app" mentioned in [How do I download an app from another country?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/85849/16575)

Comment: I don't see how a VPN will help.  I'm physically in the country, and I'm using a SIM card from within that country.  I tried downloading HOLA, I'm able to search for and find the app, but not install it because when it asks for my credentials it tells me the app is incompatible with my device.

Comment: Can you check the CSC code here and find a way to change it if it is still showing USA http://www.droidtutorials.com/tutorials/all-htc-one-m8-secret-codes.html

Comment: Your comment contradicts with your question then, giyad: you ask how to download an app from another region/country, but your issue is that app doesn't install because it's not compatible with your device. The two are not even remotely related.See:[Why are some apps on the market incompatible with my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15814/16575) / [How does Google Play work out if an app is compatible with my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35016/16575)

Comment: No I don't contradict myself I just seem to have not written the question out clearly.  I've included updates, hope that clears it up.  The issue is that I have a USA gmail account because I live in the US.  But I'm traveling right now, I have a local sim card (not the USA one), and I'm trying to download an app in the country where I am, but it keeps showing me the USA equivalent.  I'll look into the incompatibility though.

Comment: Got it working by installing the APK.  Its definitely an account region issue.

Comment: @giyad Maybe you write up an answer with the steps performed, and then accept it? It's [absolutely legit to answer your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, went ahead and did that, wanted to give the credit to Matt_Roberts though since he suggested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two ways I was able to solve this.  I preferred to use the APK method, but the other method was to create a google account in that country and add it.  APK method was cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I found for this issue which also works for things like getting Netflix content for other regions, is to use a VPN service.

I personally use VPN Unlimited at the moment though there are plenty of others available. However, for the vast majority of these you are required to pay some sort of subscription (luckily I got mine on an offer of lifetime usage for $29.99).

I am in the UK and all I need to do with this app is open it, select a server in the region of choice and then turn on the VPN service and for all intents and purposes any website or app that looks for a region thinks I am in the same region as my chosen server (I usually use one in the US).

I am sure there may be cost free versions available but I suspect they will be at some performance cost such as limited download usage or bandwidth but its worth looking into.

Comment: How does the VPN help?  I'm in the country physically, and I have a local sim card, but my google account is not letting e download the app.  The issue as I understand it is coming from my account itslef no?  I'm testing out HOLA right now, which is a free VPN

Comment: Most apps and internet pages look at the origin of your IP address. A VPN masks your originating IP address and makes it appear as though you are using the one in the servers location, hence the app or web page thinks that is the location you are in. I say most as some apps may indeed look at your account settings but I have successfully used VPN to get apps that are available in the US before or not at all available the UK (which is sadly a few). If you don't like this solution or can't get it to work, you may be able to download the APK file for the app separately and manually install it.

Comment: I just used the APK like you suggested, can't accept your answer because its not the VPN thats the issue.  I'm able to use the app fine once installed, the issue was getting google to let me install it via the play store.  I'm sure its an account thing, not sure where that setting would be though. By adding another google account created in the Middle East, I was able to find and install the app.  I preferred to use the APK in the end though because I don't want to have multiple accounts.

Comment: VPN is absolutely useless...  I have the exact same issue.  Account is a US Google account but I actually live in South Korea right now.  For various reasons I don't want to change regions because I would lose access to some things (music for example).  I am unable to download Korean region apps off the play store.  I both live in South Korea and have a South Korean SIM card (and I have for several years now)

Comment: @Goblinlord this is almost certainly useless now, however for some apps I have had this method work in the now distant past though also having to set the locale too thinking about it. Side loading seems to be the best way to do it in any case.

Answer (score -1):

You could try just downloading the APK file and try installing the app that way.

Comment: [OP got it to work by intsalling the APK](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/133335/#comment167285_133335)